# Oracle Reports 10g Crash When I Change Fonts of Text

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oraclereports

When I change fonts of text items (When I changed about 5-6 of it), Oracle Reports Crashes. It gives error message "Not Responding". Why? How can I solve it?

Device OS: Windows 10 Pro
RAM: 8 GB
64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Forms (which is a fine piece of software), Reports is one of most unstable tools I've ever worked with. Yes, it tends to crash *without a reason*. It isn't even "don't do this because it'll crash" so that you could create your own "don't do it" list. It happens for any reason - in your current case, when you change a font.

So, what to do?

- check My Oracle Support (previously called *Metalink*) to see whether there's a patch for your Reports (i.e. Developer Suite) version
- save frequently so that changes you've made aren't lost (and you'll have to do everything again)
- reboot sometimes helps
- I've installed Developer Suite 10g onto a virtual machine that runs under Windows XP (which is/was a certified combination). Have a look at certification matrices; if operating system + Reports version isn't certified, there's really no guarantee that it'll work.

  - as I've told you - even if it *is* certified, it crashes anyway

Unfortunately, I don't have a *magic wand* to solve your problems. Be patient as much as you can. Good luck, I sympathize with you.